# ubuntu on nexus 4 stuck on right swipe during tour

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I just install Ubuntu touch on my Nexus 4, but I am stuck during the second (right) swipe in the tour. Is it possible to skip this step?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try a reboot by pressing the power key for about 4 seconds until the power menu appears. Then tap to Reboot.

Or try pressing the powerkey for 10 seconds until the screen becomes black to force a hard reboot.